# PHP Foreach Loop Date Format and Reverse Order Populating Data

Tags: php

I have the the following code where it populates sql data to an html table. When I tried to format the date for "order_date", somehow, I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone in here know how to format the date to show in month day, year (May 3, 20015 for example) format? The syntax that I used date("M-d-y", strtotime($row['order_date'])) doesn't seem to work. The code that I have below only work for populating data but not with the date format for the order_date that I want. Also, how do I change the code if I want to populate the last item in the sql first? The code that I have now populates data from the first row to last, but I want to change the populating order from last row data to first row. Any help?

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `contract_number`, `property_name`, `property_address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `status`, `order_date` FROM `".$email."`";
        $result = $DB_CON->query($sql);

```
    // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
    if($result !== false) {
      $data_row = '<table class="table table-striped tablesorter">'
                . '<thead>'
                  . '<tr>'
                  . '<th>ID</th>'
                  . '<th>Contract Number</th>'
                  . '<th>Property Name</th>'
                  . '<th>Street Address</th>'
                  . '<th>City</th>'
                  . '<th>State</th>'
                  . '<th>Zip</th>'
                  . '<th>Date</th>'
                  . '<th>Status</th>'
                  . '</tr>'
                . '<tbody>';

      foreach($result as $row) {
        $data_row .=  '<tr>'
            . '<td scope="row" class="id-c text-center">'.$row['id'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['contract_number'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['property_name'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['property_address'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['city'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['state'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['zip'].'</td>'
            . '<td>' .date("M-d-y", strtotime($row['order_date'])).'</td>'
            . '<td>' .$row['status'].'</td>'; 
      }
    }
    $data_row .=  '</tbody>' 
                . '</table>';
    echo $data_row;
```

Comment: `date("F d, Y");` Will work. However, there are other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you can update your query to order the results by order date descending. So the most recent order will appear first. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, contract_number, property_name, property_address, city, state, zip, status, order_date FROM ".$email." ORDER BY order_date DESC"; $result = $DB_CON->query($sql);
```

Secondly as RepeaterCreeper suggested in the comments you can change this line:

```
. '<td>' .date("M-d-y", strtotime($row['order_date'])).'</td>'
```

to this:

```
. '<td>' .date("F d, Y", strtotime($row['order_date'])).'</td>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David. The code now works the way it was intended.